# Proof by contradiction. Which statement has to be shown to be false?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the following statement:

Show that if $B=(b_1,....,b_n)$ is a basis of a vector space V, then there is no list of vectors of length $n-1$ that spans V.

I would like to prove this by contradiction. Therefore I assume that without loss of generality the list of vectors $(b_1,....,b_{n-1})$ spans V. Since B was a basis of V, it follows that $b_n \neq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \lambda_i b_i$, but since $b_n \in V$, it follows that span$(b_1,....,b_{n-1}) \neq V$. Therefore there is no list of vectors of length $n-1$ that spans V.

Is this proof valid? Can I prove a contradiction by showing that the statement that I assumed to be true is false?

Comment: Well, if I read this proof, I would like to know why can you assume that $(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_{n-1})$ is a list of vectors that span $V$?

Comment: The list of $n-1$ vectors need not be $(b_1,\ldots ,b_{n-1})$

Comment: @Calle the assumption is the premise of his proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan, no, the assumption is that there is *a* list of $n-1$ vectors that span $V$, not that the there is a sublist of $(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n)$ that spans $V$.

Comment: Well as far as I know, in proofs of contradiction I can assume the negation of the statement that I want to prove to be true and from that prove something that is false. I guess I need to choose an arbitrary basis of length n-1 then. But I don't see how I can prove that an element of B is not in the span of those n-1 vectors then.

Comment: You have a basis $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ of $V$. You want to suppose there is a basis of $V$ of size $n-1$. Call this supposed basis $\{a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}\}$. Now ask yourself: can you express these basis vectors in terms of the basis $\{b_i\}$? Then try to find a linear combination of the $b_i$'s which is not a linear combination of the $a_i$'s.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by this statement: Now ask yourself: can you express these basis vectors in terms of the basis  $\{b_i\}$. Do you mean I should try to write $\forall i\in\{1,...,n-1\}: a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\lambda_ib_i$?